# assertion failed while debugging Boost.Python module

Tags: python, c++, boost, build, boost-python

I want to debug/create this Boost.Python module:

```
void func()
{
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ogwa_acc)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("func", func);
}
```

But every time I get this Message and the module doesn't get created:

```
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Program Files\Python38\python38_d.dll
File: D:\a\1\s\Objects\unicodeobject.c
Line: 11676

Expression: _Py_HashSecret_Initialized

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts

(Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)
```

Unfortunately, I can not do anything with this message. For example, I do not have a folder "D:\a". I hope someone can help me.

I am grateful for any help! Thank you so much!